# The scroll under material top tabs is not detected anymore since Expo Go 49 on iOS

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

#### Presentation

I'm currently developing a mobile app using Expo Go. For navigate between screens, I use React Navigation and recently, I have integrated a top navigation bar using [@react-navigation/material-top-tabs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/) which is a library developed by React Navigation.

My aim is to reproduce this kind of [design](https://dribbble.com/shots/8157039-Travel-App) in my app

#### Behaviour I want

I would like for all bottom content to be scrollable above the top content when you start scrolling with your finger on the bottom content.

#### Problem

With Expo 48, everything working correctly. But since Expo Go v49 (with expo dependencies updated), the scroll is not detected under tab content.

[Image that explain the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWX0s.png)

#### What I've noticed

- I checked React Navigation versions and there were no changes.
- Working on Expo SDK 48 but not in SDK 49
- It's working on Android
- The only changes are the version of React Native and Expo SDK.
- I checked React Native changelogs but I didn't see nothing interesting.

#### How to reproduce

I created a [minimal example built with Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@clemfrontend/stack-overflow-demo-material-top-bar-scroll-error?platform=ios) to reproduce the problem.

⚠️ **Try to switch between Expo SDK 48 and 49 to see the difference (from bottom right)**

#### Question

I tried a lot of things but I didn't found something. Someone have an idea to fix this ?